# Fetching UUID with NamedNativeQuery: [B cannot be cast to java.util.UUID

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid

I have a special Hibernate query which I had to write as `NamedNativeQuery`. This looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XYZ")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = [...],
        query = " SELECT DISTINCT uuid [...]" 
    )
})
public class XyzEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type = "uuid-binary")
    @Column(name = "uuid", columnDefinition = "RAW(32)", nullable = false)
    private UUID uuid;
}
```

The query itself works. The result set is accessed in this way:

```
public List<UUID> getXyz() {
    final Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery([...]);
    final List<UUID> resultList = query.getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

But now, if I try to iterate over this result list, I get `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.util.UUID`

The invocation looks like this:

```
public void abc() {
    final List<UUID> uuids = service.getXyz();
   
    //the start of the loop causes java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
    for (UUID uuid : uuids) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Obviously Hibernate cannot map the NamedNativeQuery result to a Java UUID properly because the content seems to be just binary. What's the proper way to handle this?

Comment: UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[]) ?

Comment: What dialect are you using?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

Comment: @shikida When I just return `byte[]` from the queries and use `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes` then, Hibernate does not find this uuid with a JPQL query then as I use it in the for...loop. That means this UUID is somehow not valid. Moreover, even if this would work, this seems to be a workaround. I would expect that Hibernate can do the proper mapping by itself.